# Complex projective plane model of spin-1 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, representation-theory

Is the complex projective plane $\mathbb{C}P^2$ a model for spin one particles in the same way that the Bloch sphere is a model for spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles?

More precisely, it is my understanding that the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$ fibrates over the Bloch sphere $\mathbb{C}P$, where each circle on the unit sphere fibrates to a point on the Bloch sphere. This is consistent with the 'rays in $\mathbb{C}^2$' definition of $\mathbb{C}P$, since each ray stereographically projects onto a circle on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which then fibrates to a point on the Bloch sphere, giving an isomorphism between the definitions.

Does the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^3$ fibrate over the complex projective plane $\mathbb{C}P^2$ in the same manner, or at least a similar one? Are the points in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ fibrations of circles on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^3$ or something like this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration#Complex_Hopf_fibrations

Comment: @Jake I take it this is a positive answer?  I'm not familiar with bundles.

Comment: Yes. A circle bundle just means the fibers are circles, like the standard Hopf fibration of S^3 over S^2 you described.

Comment: Much appreciated!